# Akka broadcast ask doesn't deliver to all routees

Tags: scala, akka, broadcast

I am learning to use broadcast messages in Akka routers. Is there a way to receive responses for `ask` from all the routees to the router?

I have this sample code.

`Master.scala`

```
object Master {
    case object brdcst
}

class Master extends Actor {
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

    val router: ActorRef = context.actorOf (RoundRobinPool (3).props(Props[Worker]), "router")

    override def receive: Receive = {
        case brdcst => {
            val future = router ? Broadcast(brdcst)
            val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration)
            println("result = " + result)
        }
    }
}

object MasterTest extends App {
    val actorSystem = ActorSystem("ActorSystem")
    val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[master], "root")
    actor ! brdcst
}
```

`Worker.scala`

```
class Worker extends Actor {
    val routee = context.actorOf(Props[Worker], "routee")

    override def receive: Receive = {
        case brdcst => sender() ! self.path.name
    }
}
```

This code gives the following output

```
result = $a
[INFO] [10/16/2018 21:47:07.484] [ActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://ActorSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://ActorSystem/user/root/router/$a#340358688] to Actor[akka://ActorSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://ActorSystem/deadLetters]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [10/16/2018 21:47:07.504] [ActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] [akka://ActorSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://ActorSystem/user/root/router/$b#-151225340] to Actor[akka://ActorSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://ActorSystem/deadLetters]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

So the reply is coming only from one routee. How to get responses from all the routees? (Maybe as a list like `result = [$a, $b, $c]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ask` (`?`) creates an internal actor to handle replies. This internal actor handles only a single reply and is automatically shut down: this is the reason you get only the first response, while the responses from the other two routees go to dead letters.

To get the desired behavior, use `tell` (`!`) and collect the responses from the routees. For example:

```
class Master extends Actor {
  val numRoutees = 3
  val router = context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(numRoutees).props(Props[Worker]), "router")

  def handleMessages(replies: Set[String] = Set()): Receive = {
    case brdcst =>
      router ! Broadcast(brdcst)
    case reply: String =>
      val updatedReplies = replies + reply
      if (updatedReplies.size == numRoutees) {
        println("result = " + updatedReplies.mkString("[", ",", "]"))
      }
      become(handleMessages(updatedReplies))
  }

  def receive = handleMessages
}
```

In the above example, the master encodes the routees' replies as part of its state, using [`become`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#become-unbecome).

Also, don't use `Await` in actors.